# Cygwin hangs on Perl script: Nothing seems to fix

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, which seems to be part of the problem.  At first my `cpan` would  hang when I would try to `install CPAN` from the shell prompt.

I tried restarting my computer, and a variety of attempts to use `rebaseall` and `peflagsall` from `ash`- even starting a new base for the dll's (the command was something suggested on a cygwin mailing list- something like `rebaseall -vb 0x730000`).

Should I just uninstall Cygwin and try to do a total reinstall?  I have all the dependencies that `cpan` should need (i.e. `gcc-4`).

I'm getting pretty desperate here- I'm getting error messages that talk about failed dlls if I try to use modules installed from CPAN (specifically, `JSON::XS`).

Any help you could offer would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the cpan interaction?

Comment: The error message I've been getting when attempting to `install CPAN` displays `100803213 [main] perl 5592 child_copy: loaded dll data write copy failed, 0x73241000..0x732427F0, done 0, windows pid 5636, Win32 error 487`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complaining about missing dlls when installing is a known bug I believe, and appears for a lot of modules. Most modules are still installed and still work however. In my experience, you need to force install most modules as well, as there is almost always some test that fails.

While I personally prefer perl from the cygwin environment, there is one good reason for installing Strawberryperl; the need for 64 bit support which cygwin does not support. If you are going to work with large XML data structures using XML::Simple for instance, the 1.5-2GB that 32-bit Windows support will not take you far, and Strawberryperl will come to your rescue. And thanks to perl portability, and apart from keeping two sets of perl's installed on the same computer, the is no problem doing development using cygwin, and then running it "in production" using 64-bit Strawberryperl.

Comment: Awesome.  I wish I could upvote you, but I don't have the reputation yet.  Would StrawberryPerl allow me to execute scripts from the command line using `perl`?  I have a `wget` function that's installed independently of Cygwin that works like this.

Comment: Also, how would one alter the traditional practice of using `#!/bin/perl` at the beginning of scripts to make them directly executable from the command line?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: You execute script in Windows (outside of Cygwin) by doing a `perl myscriptname.pl` or similar (assuming strawberryperl is in your path, or alternativly using a full path like `c:\strawberry\bin\perl.exe myscript.pl`. Unix-style hashbangs do not work in Windows (outside of Cygwin). If needed, you can create a (DOS-style) batch file (.bat) that calls `perl yourscript.pl` for you, optionally changing directory and setting up paths if your perl script does not take care of this itself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing `cygwin` and then building Perl on top of that? You will be far more successful if you use [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) which comes with its own cygwin environment that will allow you to build and install most CPAN modules if you need them

Comment: I will look into it, thanks.  I have using the `perl` and `cpan` modules from Cygwin's `setup.exe`.

Comment: Strawberry Perl has a nice suite of gnu tools, but it is not at all the same as a Cygwin environment. If all the OP wants to do is run Perl on a Windows machine, this is a good solution. If the OP wants to run perl from Cygwin, this will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you're hitting is the difference between the regular shell (which will normally be bash and give you a `$` prompt on Cygwin) and the cpan shell (which will give you a prompt like `cpan[1]>`).

In the cpan shell, `install CPAN` will refresh a bunch of Perl scripts from the CPAN repository. From a bash shell, `install CPAN` just doesn't make sense: [`install`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install) is a program for installing packages you've just built; it has nothing in particular to do with Perl or with how you install packages on Cygwin.

You can enter the CPAN shell by running `cpan` at bash shell prompt. But I don't think that's what you need. What you actually want to do is just run the following:

```
cpan JSON::XS
```

Comment: I've been attempting to execute `install CPAN` and `install JSON::XS` from within the `cpan` shell, which is where I have been getting the error message (also have seen similar error messages trying to run a perl script that uses those modules when I had thought I finally got them to install).  Probably could have made that clearer, sorry.